# Custom media player in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, visibility

I am trying to make a custom media player where when ever the music start a loader will start and when the music is paused or ends the the loader goes invisible .This is what i am trying to get when the button is clicked .[image: this is i am trying to get].How to set the desired output.I am using the following gradel

```
 compile 'com.leo.simplearcloader:simplearcloader:1.0.+'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
```

my xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.union.playerfront1.MainActivity"
>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="invisible"
android:id="@+id/load1">
<com.leo.simplearcloader.SimpleArcLoader
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:id="@+id/loader"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    custom:arc_style="simple_arc"
    custom:arc_speed="medium"
    custom:arc_margin="3dp"
    >
</com.leo.simplearcloader.SimpleArcLoader>
</RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/profile_image"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            app:civ_border_width="2dp"
            app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

my java code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
boolean isPressed = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer =MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.song);
    final RelativeLayout real=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.load1);
    final Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
if (isPressed){
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.profile);
real.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
mediaPlayer.start();
}
        }
    });

}
}
```

How I can change the visibility of the loader on the base that a song is playing or it is stopped I am able to set the button visibility properly.How i can set the visibility on the basis of song pause,song start,song stop?

Comment: Your `isPressed` is always false. So, that's why nothing happens on the click.

Comment: Now when i set the is pressed to true the circular image that i m using gets larger what to do with that